# Excel front end to SSAS from different machine shows all data despite dimension security

Tags: excel, ssas, ssas-2008

On the same machine as where the SSAS is, I can simulate the security as follows, to have different results due to the applied Dimensional security:

```
runas /user:dom\usr1 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"

runas /user:dom\usr2 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE"
```

However, when I run those from other machine, I can see all members of the Dimension; as if the security never been set.

The Dimensional security is applied by making a single Role with those two users having different permitted Dimension members.

Is the only way to apply the cube security is through [HTTP](http://www.scoop.it/t/ssas/p/2237470862/configure-http-access-on-iis-7-0)?

Answer (score 1):

No, HTTP isn't the only way.  Windows Authentication should work fine.

Can you run a profiler trace against the SSAS instance to confirm what credentials are being used when connecting from the other machine?

Here's a screenshot of the trace events you want to capture in the profiler trace..."Audit Login" is the main one you want to look at.
[image]

Comment: Following the HTTP way of trying to secure the cube access using Excel, hopefully it will ask for user credentials, that's what I am looking for, I have yet to try it.

I have tried using SSRS, where we can force the user to key in the credentials in prior of accessing the cube based report, but that's less interactive. I may proceed using SharePoint Excel services for this.

OK, I use Profiler only to capture the MDX issued against the cube. As for the "logon", what keyword shall I focus on please? Thanks.

Comment: If your users are all on the same domain, I highly recommend going with Windows Authentication.  Forcing your users to login each time (whether through SSRS, Excel, or any other client tool) is going to become very annoying to them.

Comment: But then again, if you are going to use SharePoint and the Analysis Services server is on a separate box, configuring Kerberos may be more than you're willing to take on...in which case HTTP-authentication may be more appealing.

Comment: OK, through Profiler Audit Login, I managed to get the correct userID when I "run as" the Excel. However, as said, the Excel still shows all members of the Dimension that I restricted. Therefore, I will explore the usage of SharePoint Excel service, HTTP, or perhaps PowerPivot. Further suggestions are welcomed. Thanks for the advice.